# (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1045, u"Access denied for user 'cmr378'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")

Tags: python, mysql, database

I am currently trying to fetch data from a MySql database that I created using MySql workbench and then trying to display it on my front end. I am relatively new when it comes to MySql and databases. I came across the following while I was trying to run app.py:

```
(pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1045, u"Access denied for user 
'cmr378'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
```

The following is my database uri:

```
database_uri = "mysql+pymysql://username:1234@localhost:3306/bbdp"
```

I correctly fill in the username and password according to the MySql workbench connection yet still I obtain the error.

Without the use of shell commands (because I am not to familiar with the mysql ones) can someone explain why this is occurring and how to resolve the issue?

Comment: which PyMySQL version? Which MySQL version? Can you `SHOW CREATE USER cmr378@localhost` (omit auth data /password hash if you want)?